# Loading a SQLite table into DatagridView (Powershell)

Tags: winforms, sqlite, powershell, datagridview

Most of the examples are for C# or other languages so here's what I created in Powershell to load a table with an unknown number of columns into a new DatagridView.  If someone knows of a more built-in way to do this with fewer custom functions, please share.

Comment: What's your question? Is your answer below working or is something wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

```
#SQL function
Function SQLite-Query {
param (
  [String]$query
)
#write-host $query
$sql = $con.CreateCommand()
$sql.CommandText = $query
$adapter = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataAdapter $sql
$data = New-Object System.Data.Datatable
[void]$adapter.Fill($data)
return $data
}

#Load the Data
$result = SQLite-Query $query
$columnNames = $result | gm -MemberType Property | select -ExpandProperty name
$DGV.Rows.Clear()
$DGV.Columns.Clear()
foreach ($cname in $columnNames) {
  $DGV.Columns.Add($cname,$cname)
}
foreach ($row in $result) {
  $rowindex = $DGV.Rows.Add()
  foreach ($c in $columnNames) {
    $DGV.Rows[$rowindex].Cells[$c].value = $row[$c]
  }
}
```